# Can't download microsoft teams deb file

Tags: deb, microsoft, video-conversion, microsoft-teams

does anyone know how to install teams on Ubuntu ? The official deb file is 404 [link](https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams/pool/main/t/teams/teams_1.5.00.23861_amd64.deb) ?

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft has [abandoned](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/end-of-the-road-for-teams-linux-desktop-client/m-p/3630968) making a full-fat desktop app for Teams.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, now Microsoft has now removed the Teams deb file for Linux can refer to [ms-teams-for-linux-not-available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1182762/ms-teams-for-linux-not-available), here someone has posted the link to download teams .deb file its working, I have used this as well (for work & school accounts)

Link: https://web.archive.org/web/20221130115842/https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams/pool/main/t/teams/teams_1.5.00.23861_amd64.deb

[image]

Other than this I guess you can simply install Teams (home/personal accounts) as Progressive Web App(PWA), I am using that via Edge (can do it in other browsers as well) just log in online in Teams account from a browser https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/microsoft-teams/log-in then install it as PWA

[image]

Now you will be able to find it on a PC as an application.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The official one is abandoned and you can't download. You might be able to get the deb package from archives but it may or may not work. Just go to calendar and click new meeting. You'll see a blank window. I'm a maintainer of the unofficial version (web version packed using electron). Reasonably active community and it's getting more and more active lately. Check out:

https://github.com/IsmaelMartinez/teams-for-linux

1. You can use the releases page in github repo and download the package of your choice. You have to manually download and update when there is a new release.
2. Or `snap` with auto update.
3. Or `flatpak` with auto update `flatpak update`
4. Or even download from deb ppa hosted at cloudsmith.

If you have queries, please ask question in the repo.

Comment: May I ask about the key benefits of it? Please consider that we can have the PWA (official I think). 
And according to my experience, the options/settings are the same as in the PWA.

Comment: If you're happy with PWA, please continue with that. There are many reasons why people use `teams-for-linux`. You can try it yourself. Please go through the repo documentation and understand if that's any better than PWA.

Comment: I'm not "happy" with the PWA. I think I had more options e.g. Device Settings in the old official app. That's why I was looking for a better alternative. BTW I've installed your app. And thanks for your contribution!

Comment: @arif, if you find issues, please post an issue in the repo. We'll do our best to resolve it.

Comment: Installing this currently fails. "/etc/apt/keyrings/teams-for-linux.asc: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

That is available as snap, I cannot find it as deb anymore. It looks available as flatpak too.

[Snapstore](https://snapcraft.io/teams-for-linux).

[Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/com.github.IsmaelMartinez.teams_for_linux).

The flatpak version is described as "unofficial", I guess both are.

[image]

Comment: You've linked to an unofficial snap. The official one, published by Microsoft was at https://snapcraft.io/teams - but as I mentioned, they have abandoned making a desktop app for Linux, and have told users to use a browser window instead.

Comment: @popey -  All that is said explicitly above. But the question was `does anyone know how to install teams on Ubuntu ?` - Also: the app may be unofficial, but snapcraft is related to Ubuntu and the community. Using the browser for teams, whatsapp etc is what I also do no matter if an "app" is available or not (which in my opinion, deb or not,  is just a chrome-based browser marketed as "X app" etc). -An answer is supposed to be useful, to the OP and others too, now and in the future.  Please focus on expanding yours and leave mine alone.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently they killed teams for Linux, since they abandoned their desktop app and made the webapp only available for chromium based browsers.