# Did microsoft remove Teams from Linux desktop?

Tags: 22.04, microsoft, microsoft-teams

I'm attempting to run MS Teams on Ubuntu 22.04 as I have for many months now and suddenly I get an error that states "Operation failed with unexpected error."

I also notice that when search for information about Teams that I find the [latest MS  documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/get-clients?tabs=Windows#desktop-clients) doesn't mention how to install on Linux:

[image: desktop clients - linux not listed]

I also found a link that states: [Microsoft Teams progressive web app now available on Linux](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/download-app#allDevicesSection)

However, clicking the "Learn MOre" link on that page is a circular reference and does not take you to any instructions to install on Linux or download the .deb as it allowed in the past.

**Uninstalled / Installed**

I uninstalled the app and tried installing again I saw the following:

[image: failed to connect]

**Getting the Original Deb pkg**

Originally I downloaded the PWA deb pkg from an official microsoft site (the one that mentions that the desktop app is gone).

I also searched around to see if Microsoft makes the PWA installation package available anywhere at this time.

It seems they removed it a while back but luckily I still have it in my downloads directory.

I also found a [Microsoft link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/teams150023861amd64deb-not-found/43b48ef4-7d94-4723-908b-ddb0a60c68cf) that shows that you can get the .deb for installation at: https://mirror.slackware.hr/sources/teams/teams_1.5.00.23861_amd64.deb

It seems as if they are hiding the PWA too and probably not actually supporting it either.  Probably will be just a browser page in the futre.

Has Microsoft removed support for Teams on Linux?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Microsoft Teams for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1459302/install-microsoft-teams-for-ubuntu-22-04-lts)

Comment: @OrganicMarble Unfortunately, that is an old question/answer. That is not related to my question. I was using the PWA version but it seems that Microsoft has cut off the PWA now too.  
There were a lot of changes instituted with MS Teams and Office365 yesterday and I believe they are no longer supporting it on Linux.

Comment: Have you tried whether the snap version has the features you want? https://askubuntu.com/a/1457085/925128. Flatpak version link https://flathub.org/apps/com.github.IsmaelMartinez.teams_for_linux

Comment: @OrganicMarble Also, your vote to close it completely incorrect.   Why didn't you wait until I replied about the other question?

Comment: @cipricus The official link to the flatpak (shown on the askubutnu answer you posted) does not even exist any more.  Microsoft has removed the official link fro snapcraft.

Comment: I don't use it but was wondering whether the flatpak and snap versions are working. I have updated the link

Comment: @user68186  That's the point.  I'm use PWA also but it no longer works.  It is gone today.

Comment: @cipricus What even is that flathub.org link? That's not official.  I don't want to install some rogue version of Teams.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatpak I personally trust the snap and flathub platforms. But each its own tolerance to risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason to solve this (on the PWA) I had to :

1. use browser to navigate to my organizations official Office365 login.
2. Click the teams icon on the left sidebar
   2a. outlook worked but teams failed numerous times
3. start the PWA again - it finally redirected me to my orgs login and now the Teams PWA worked again.

There were updates to office365 yesterday which were world wide. i believe it has something to do with that.

[image: office 365 teams icon]